# Codeigniter search Db, process it and redirect to rendered page on submit

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am building an app on codeigniter that the user searches for specific types of legislation.
I already have the home page built but i am having a slightly hard time in how to build the results page ( i am new to codeigniter). On submit i need the data to be posted to the back-end, and for the browser to redirect to the rendered results page.

Some options for the search are optional, so i also need to take that into consideration for the search.

Any answer helping me build this page would be appreciated

EDIT: Further clarification.
The optional parameters for the search are the hidden parameters in the view. 
When the user clicks the checkbox a list of the options displayed in db appear and he selects one of them.

Edit:Example of the structure of the db.

Id: 1

Law: Civil

Subject: Alimony

Theme: Family law

Area: divorce law

Law text : Article 1 of Law nº 12330/2012 ...

The results page return the law text.

(E.g: If the user checks the 'law' box, a list of law options appear: Civil law, penal law, etc. When he selects an option the result page is supposed to return all instances of the selected choice)

Here are the controller, model and view for the home page:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index(){

    $this->load->model('Index_model', 'index');


    $dados['law'] = $this->index->get_law();
    $dados['area'] = $this->index->get_area();
    $dados['subjects'] = $this->index->get_subject();
    $dados['themes'] = $this->index->get_theme();
    //the index model query a specific table from the db

    $this->load->view('include/header_public');
    $this->load->view('public/home', $data);

}


}
```

Model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index_model extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_index($limit = null, $offset = null){
    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }



public function get_law(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_law');
    return $query->result();
}


public function get_area(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_area');
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_subject(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_subject');
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_theme(){
    $query = $this->db->get('tb_theme');
    return $query->result();
}


}
```

View (since view is a little large, built with material design lite, i will put on only a short part of the code, since it repeats itself):

```
<main class="mdl-grid">
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="search-section">
        <h4 class="search-title">What are you searching today</h4>
        <form method="POST">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label      mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search" name="search" required>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search">Search now</label>
 </div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label  mdl-cell--8-col-desktop">

              <input type="checkbox" id="lawcheck" name="law" value="law"
              onclick='toggleLawVisibility'>
              <label for="law">Law</label>
            </div>

            <div id='lawdiv' class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label  mdl-cell--4-col-desktop">
                            <select class="browser-default" name="law" id="law" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>law</option>
                                <?php foreach($laws as $law){?>
                                <option value="<?= $law->CO_LAW?>">
                                    <?= $law->DS_LAW?>
                                </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

<!-- Code repeats for area,subject, etc -->
...
  <button type="submit"class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect btn-search">
                Search
            </button>
          </form>
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
document.getElementById('lawCheck').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('lawdiv').style.visibility = this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
};
<!--Same script for area, subject, etc -->
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: "submit i need the data to be posted to the back-end, and for the browser to redirect to the rendered results page." What does the results page look like? What data do you want to search by... I see a form with a few inputs, whats going on here? Where is your search function? (Should usually contain a LIKE stmt). As it stands your question isn't explained enough.

Comment: "Some options for the search are optional, so i also need to take that into consideration for the search." what does that even mean for us? If we don't know whats optional how can we address it?

Comment: Ow sorry, i am gonna edit and explain it better. The optional parameters are law, theme, subject, etc. 
If the user leaves the search box empty and selects an option of those parameters the result is supposed to render all instances of the db that are associated with those parameters.

If the user types something in the search box the result is supposed to render all instances of the db that contains that string he typed.

Comment: Added some clarification on the main post.

Comment: Yeah then you are probably going to also need to include relevant db structure. But to me it doesn't seem like you tried enough at this point.

Comment: Ok, will add another edit.

Yes i have tried. But so far no success at all, as i said i am a beginner on code igniter.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data ... also pictures of db structures are usually more informative ;) What are the tables `theme` `subject` `area` .etc. Do you also want to search those? Or just the law table? What is the field you want to search by?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started. Basically it searchs through different tables using the array: `$search_tbl = array('projects' => 'project_name', 'testimonials' => 'company');` where the `key` is the table name and the `value` is the field you want to search in.

```
    // controller/search/{$term}
    public function search($term = null) {

        if (!is_null($term)) {
            $term = urldecode($term);
            echo 'Term to search: ' . $term . '<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Returning all results... <br>';
        }

        $search_tbl = array('tblname1' => 'field_in_tbl1', 'tblname2' => 'field_in_tbl2');

        $master = array();

        foreach ($search_tbl as $tbl_name => $tbl_search_field) {
            $this->db->like($tbl_search_field, $term);
            $q = $this->db->get($tbl_name);
            if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                $data = array();
                $master = array_merge($master, $q->result_array());
                /*
                 * Do tables not have the same structure?
                 * You might have to do something like this to pick out only the "shared" field names
                 * Otherwise you can't loop the results in a structured way...
                 * 
                foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'field1' => $row['field1'],
                        'field2' => $row['field2']
                    );
                }
                $master = array_merge($master, $data);
                 * 
                 */
            } else {
                echo 'No results for table: ' . $tbl_name . '<br>';
            }
        }

        if (count($master) < 1) {
            echo 'No results!<br>';
        } else {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($master);
        }
    }
```